# Python Vscode Lambda issue

Tags: python, lambda

Vscode has an issue with the lambda expression when I create a function, it works until I either save the script or run the script then the code below get changed from this automatically

```
  a = lambda user : user + 10
  re = a(40)
  print(re)
```

to this

```
 def a(user): return user + 10
    re = a(40)
    print(re)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Vscode issue. It is due to pep8 auto formatting.(vscode is suggesting you the best way to write your code)
Try to disable auto format in vscode.
Go to File -> Preferences -> settings
Look for python> Formatting autopep8 path and turn it to null or something.
But I don't recommend to do that because according to pep8 :

```
"Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifie"
```

edit : 
[PEP8 Documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: mark it as solved please, so people with similar problems can profit from the answer :)